# EM Energy-momentum tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

> I'm trying to prove the following equation which is recieved by the energy momentum tensor:
> $$\partial_{\mu} T^{\mu \nu}=\frac{1}{c}j_{\mu}F^{\mu \nu}. $$

The energy momentum tensor is defined by

$$ T^{\mu \nu}= \frac{1}{4\pi}(F^{\mu \rho}F_{\rho}^{\nu}+\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\mu\nu}F_{\rho \kappa}F^{\rho \kappa}).$$

Now i determined the divergence of this equation.  My problem is that I don't understand how to do the following step with the last term of the divergence of $T$

$$-\frac{1}{2}F_{\rho \kappa}(\partial^{\rho}F^{\kappa \nu}+\partial^{\kappa}F^{\nu \rho}) = -F_{\rho \kappa}\partial^{\rho}F^{\kappa \nu}$$
and how this cancels with the second term of the divergence which is
$$F^{\mu \rho} \partial_{\mu}F_{\rho}^{\nu}.$$

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: Just write everything in terms of derivatives of $A^\mu$ and compare terms.

Comment: It's from a script of my lecture. Okay I will try.

Comment: If i write everything in terms of $$ A^{\mu}$$ I get: $$\partial^{\rho}(\partial^{\kappa}A^{\nu}-\partial^{\nu}A^{\kappa})+\partial^{\kappa}(\partial^{\nu}A^{\rho}-\partial^{\rho}A^{\nu})$$. How can I go on now?